# Access specific JSON Data

Tags: python, json, flask

Im Trying to accesss to 'dataset' in 'protocol1' or to 'zeile' which is in 'log' which is in 'protocol1'. But i cant get make it working.

I tried it with nested for loops but i dont work.

This is my JSON File.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "protocol1": {
                    "dataset": "Testdataset1",
                    "eingangssprache": "Testeingangssprache1",
                    "ausgangssprache": "Testausgangssprache1",
                    "start": "13/01/2021 04:22 1",
                    "end": "14/01/2021 16:20 1"
                },
                    "log": [
                    {
                        "zeile": "01",
                        "methode": "lang detect",
                        "language1": "german",
                        "language2": "english"
                    },
                    {
                        "zeile": "02",
                        "methode": "lang detect",
                        "language1": "german",
                        "language2": "english"
                    },
                    {
                        "zeile": "03",
                        "methode": "lang detect",
                        "language1": "german",
                        "language2": "english"
                    }
                    ]
                },
        {
            "protocol2": {
                    "dataset": "Testdataset2",
                    "eingangssprache": "Testeingangssprache1",
                    "ausgangssprache": "Testausgangssprache1",
                    "start": "13/01/2021 04:22 1",
                    "end": "14/01/2021 16:20 1"
            },
                "log": [
               {
                        "zeile": "01",
                        "methode": "lang detect es",
                        "language1": " es",
                        "language2": "english es"
                    },
                    {
                        "zeile": "01",
                        "methode": "lang detect",
                        "language1": "german es",
                        "language2": "engli essh"
                    },
                    {
                        "zeile": "01",
                        "methode": "lang dete esct",
                        "language1": "germa esn",
                        "language2": "engli essh"
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does maybe someone know how?
Im using flask which is jinja2.

---

Before it was like this

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ausgangssprache": "Testout",
            "dataset": "Test",
            "eingangssprache": "Testin",
            "end": "14/01/2021 00:00",
            "start": "13/01/2021 04:22",
            "zeile": "45",
            "methode": "language detection",
            "language1": "Testin",
            "language2": "TestLlang",
            "zusammenfassung": "Zsf"
        }
    ]
}
```

And i could get access this JSON with this html code

```html
{% for i in data_protocol %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ i.dataset }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ i.eingangssprache }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ i.ausgangssprache }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ i.start }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ i.end }}</td>

                                        <td>
......stuff ...
                                    {% endfor %}
```

the python code which is returning the json file is this

```py
json_file = open("data/table.json", "r")
    data = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close()
    data = data['data']
    return render_template('index.html',
                           column_names=['Dataset', 'Eingangssprache', 'Ausgangssprache', 'Startzeit', 'Endzeit', 'LOG'],
                           data_protocol=data)
```

I hope you can help me with that, thanks in advance

Comment: What problem you get?

Comment: i cant get the inputs from 'protocol1' i want to display the attributes from it. for example 'dataset': 'Testdataset1' how im gonna print it in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of solving problem with `jinja2` you can simplify your data. Here is the code I used to simplify your `data_set`:

```
total_dict = {}
for count, element in enumerate(data_set['data']):
    cleaned_data = {}
    for value in element.values():
        if type(value) == dict:
            cleaned_data['dataset'] = value['dataset']
            cleaned_data['eingangssprache'] = value['eingangssprache']
            cleaned_data['ausgangssprache'] = value['ausgangssprache']
            cleaned_data['start'] = value['start']
            cleaned_data['end'] = value['end']
            pass
        elif type(value) == list:
            # Store corresponding elements in one zeile_list
            zeile_list = []
            for i in value:
                # Adding all properties for each zeile
                each_list = [i['zeile'], i['methode'], i['language1'], i['language2']]
                zeile_list.append(each_list)
            
            zeile_dict = {}
            # Adding number and value of each_zeile to dictionary
            for i, v in enumerate(zeile_list):
                zeile_dict[i + 1] = v
            
            cleaned_data['zeile'] = zeile_dict
            
    
    total_dict[str(count)] = cleaned_data
```

`total_dict` dictionary will look like this after running this code:

```
{
    '0': {
        'dataset': 'Testdataset1', 
        'eingangssprache': 'Testeingangssprache1', 
        'ausgangssprache': 'Testausgangssprache1', 
        'start': '13/01/2021 04:22 1', 
        'end': '14/01/2021 16:20 1', 
        'zeile': {
            1: ['01', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english'], 
            2: ['02', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english'], 
            3: ['03', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english']}}, 
    '1': {
        'dataset': 'Testdataset2', 
        'eingangssprache': 'Testeingangssprache1', 
        'ausgangssprache': 'Testausgangssprache1', 
        'start': '13/01/2021 04:22 1', 
        'end': '14/01/2021 16:20 1', 
        'zeile': {
            1: ['01', 'lang detect es', ' es', 'english es'], 
            2: ['01', 'lang detect', 'german es', 'engli essh'], 
            3: ['01', 'lang dete esct', 'germa esn', 'engli essh']}}
}
```

Then you can simply grab all data you need with `jinja2` easily:

```
total_dict = {
    ....
}
t = jinja2.Template('''
        {% for data in total_dict.values() %}
            dataset -- {{ data['dataset'] }}
            ...
            {% for zeile_key, zeile_values in data['zeile'].items()%}
                zeile{{zeile_key}} -- {{zeile_values}}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
''')
print(t.render(total_dict=total_dict))
```

Finally, the result will look like:

```
dataset -- Testdataset1
...
            
zeile1 -- ['01', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english']
zeile2 -- ['02', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english']
zeile3 -- ['03', 'lang detect', 'german', 'english']
            
dataset -- Testdataset2
...
zeile1 -- ['01', 'lang detect es', ' es', 'english es']
zeile2 -- ['01', 'lang detect', 'german es', 'engli essh']
zeile3 -- ['01', 'lang dete esct', 'germa esn', 'engli essh']
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was the solution

Comment: Hello last 14 days i was very busy with university and stuff, and now im working at it again.

I found out that the way it displayed is not the aim.
I hope that maybe can help me out with that again.

each 'zeile' should have his own row with each other entry of 'methode', 'language1' and 'language2'